# Threejs displacement map has no effect

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I try to engrave text using displacement map however text looks only textured but with no engraved effect.

My code below

```
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(root + '/img/textures/map.png')
texture.flipY = false;
var to = scene.getObjectByName('M-Top')
to.material.transparent = true
to.material.map = texture
to.material.displacementMap = texture
to.material.displacementScale = -0.1
to.material.needsUpdate = true
```

The displacement image:
[image: Image 1]

The result:
[image: Image 2]

The Vertices:
[image: Vertices]

With BumpMap and Ambient Occlusion:
[image: BumpMap]

Comment: Try enabling `material.wireframe = true` and check that there are vertices in the area you are trying to displace? Displacement maps in three.js only move vertices – if there are no vertices in the white area, nothing will happen. Using the texture as a `.bumpMap` will give a more subtle effect but could work without geometry in the region.

Comment: I tried with BumMap, however quality is very low

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any vertices in the middle of the cylinder for the displacement texture to displace. Text would require a lot of vertices, I'm not sure that's a practical choice here. If you aren't able to do this in a modeling program like Blender, it may be worth looking at a [CSG plugin for three.js](https://github.com/gkjohnson/three-bvh-csg). CSG would require generating geometry for the text (e.g. THREE.TextGeometry) and then subtracting it from the mesh.

Comment: I tried with CSG plug-in and indeed it works very well for plan surface. 
I tried a plug-in to bend the text, but the result when the text is bended on the height is not what I expect. Too angulous.

Answer (score 0):

Like Don says in the comments, displacement map works by moving verticies, of which you have none in the areas you are trying to displace.
A bump map does not work with verticies and it's quality is related to the resolution of the texture used.
So you basically have two options..

1. Add verticies where you want the displacement to affect, which will require quite a few verticies and is probably not what you want.
2. Or, **use a bump map** with a bump map texture that has a **high enough resolution** to get an acceptable result.

As a site note, a [canvas can be used as a texture](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=canva#webgl_materials_texture_canvas), so you could generate the bump map texture on the fly with a canvas, which could allow for dynamic text

Comment: Ok let’s try with a better resolution but same png used as map texture has good quality.

Comment: I updated my code to use canvas + bumpmap + ambient occulsion. It looks much better however it looks still not very engraved.
Is there a way to improve a little bit ? get shadow and have a feelings that is realy en graved ?